# Scrape the HTML from a webpage after rendering the JSON/Javascript without Selenium while supporting POSTing

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, pyqt

I'm trying to use the following code, which works fine but it doesn't let the JavaScript run first, which means I don't get the desired HTML from the webpage.

I've had a look at `DryScrape` but as far as I can see it doesn't support posting like you can see in the `auto_login()` function, the same goes for `PyQt4`.

The website in question has 4 bits of JSON "lists"? that form the page on load/render; if I view the source it doesn't show nicely and I can't easily find stuff in it, however if I "Inspect Element" on the page the HTML looks perfect and then I can easily look through it with `BeautifulSoup`.

I know I could use `Selenium`, but this isn't what I want to do mainly because of wanting it to run in the background, I may be able to use `PhantomJS` or `PyVirtualDisplay` to do this but this would only be as a last resort.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'}
SESSION = requests.session()
RESPONSE = requests.Response

email = "mail@mail.com"
pass = "password123"

def auto_login():
    global RESPONSE
    url = "https://website.com/log.php"
    payload = {
        "log":email,
        "pwd":pass,
    "finish":"https://website.com/listed/public/gen1/",
    }
    RESPONSE = SESSION.post(url, data=payload, headers=HEADERS, verify=False)

def process_html():
    PROCESSED_HTML = BeautifulSoup(RESPONSE.content, 'html.parser')
    return PROCESSED_HTML

def main():
    auto_login()
    PROCESSED_HTML = get_html()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I easily render a webpage's JavaScript using my script (modified), preferably with `PyQt4` (`DryScrape` won't install correctly on my Windows 10, Python 2.7 for some reason) without using `Selenium`.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you try Selenium yet?

Comment: Buaban, nope, that's a last choice option that I don't yet know how to do, I need to look further into a background `Selenium` route and figure out that would work. I'm looking mainly for an option to use `PyQt4` and make my code change the minimal amount of changes.

Comment: running headless selenium tests is really trivial...it's just a few lines of code to integrate with Xvfb:  https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper#testing-example-headless-selenium-webdriver-tests

Comment: "[...] doesn't let the JavaScript run"  Are you doing something in your code that would run JavaScript? It's hard to understand your thinking.

Comment: @rakslice No... that is what I am asking about, I've given you a copy of some code that works but doesn't render/run the javascript.

Comment: Ypu need to share the url,, you can mimic come ajax calls etc,, to get the data you want but  there is no silver bullet for scraping sites

Comment: So, just to be sure I'm following, you want to go to a site, view the html, javascript, and JSON, as source, separate out the three of them, and save them off?

Comment: @JordonBirk Nope, Load the page and grab the HTML after the javascript has ran which populates several json fields into HTML otherwise the source of the page would just have blank sections with json lists in them.

Comment: So, I definitely recommend changing the variable name from `pass` to `password` to avoid conflict with keywords, but, apart from that, I can't think of anything that I'm sure can work as a  background process. Have you tried [Scrapy}(http://scrapy.org/doc/)? That  might do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get dryscape to work for me, so I cannot test this; however, I think this idea/hack may work - might need some minor tweaks.

The idea is that you create a small, local HTML file with a form and the params you need to pass. This HTML file is created in Python so that you can pass in the values to each param.

According to the docs, dryscrape can submit forms, so you submit your form and it should get you to where you need to go.

Something like:

```
import dryscrape

payload = {'log':email, 'pwd':pass, 'finish':'https://website.com/listed/public/gen1/'}

html = '''
    <form action="https://website.com/log.php" method="POST">
        <input name="log" type="text" value="{log}">
        <input name="pwd" type="password" value="{pwd}">
        <input name="finish" type="text" value="{finish}">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    '''.format(**payload)

with open('./temp.html','w') as hf:
    hf.write(html)

sess = dryscrape.Session(base_url = './') # maybe 'file://' is needed?

q = sess.visit('/temp.html')
q.form().submit()

# Remainder of your code to follow...
```

Again, I am not able to test this on my own, so there may be some minor tweaks needed.

Not very elegant, but just a thought... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some proxy services have an option of rendering the javascript on the page. The one I use for work is called ProxyCrawl but I'm sure others exist. It's a paid service though (per request), and may not work for your application. Just an idea. Most of my scraping project's flow is like: ProxyCrawl -> Scrapy -> Database.